# how to receive data in constructor again in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, rebuild

I have a button in a page.
and a class named MySdClass.
In my main class i have a constructor that receive some data from MySdClass.
i want wen user click on button the constructor of that page receive data from MySdClass again.
The code I imagine in my mind does not work:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:./SdClass.dart';

void main(){
runApp(MainClass(inputData: MySdClass.data,));
}

class MainClass extends StatelessWidget {
final String data;
const MainClass({Key? key, required this.data}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Row(
  children: [
    Container(
      const Text(this.widget.data),
    ),
    ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){//what should be here?}, child: const 
Text('next')),
     ],
   );
  }
 }
```

Comment: do you want refresh your data?

Comment: @AlexRintt yes should be refresh but by constructor

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: @AlexRinttI am new to Flutter.
I want to make a quiz app.
The solution that came to my mind is to give the question number to the main page through the constructor so that it can show the relevant questions and options.
setState is a good solution, but since I have a slider in the main page that has a separate class and I used various widgets, setState only changes one widget.

Answer (score 2):

```
void main(){
  runApp(MainClass(inputData: MySdClass.data, onPressed:(){
  "Perform some action and you can send data again through this contructor"
});
 }

 class MainClass extends StatelessWidget {
 final String data;
 void Function() onPressed;
 MainClass({Key? key, required this.data,required this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Row(
  children: [
Container(
  const Text(this.widget.data),
),
ElevatedButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: const 
 Text('next')),
 ],
  );
 }
     }
```

Comment: i need to receive not send!!

Comment: when parent state refreshed the children stateless widget automatically updated with latest data